# mean() in R thinks na.rm is an object

Tags: r

I am running R x64 3.2.5 in RStudio 0.99.896 on Windows 8.1.

I am creating a function in R for the R programming course on Coursera.  I am trying to read all the csv files in the directory 'specdata' and take an average of each of two pollutants: 'sulfate' and 'nitrate'.  I have the following code:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332) {
 monitors <- list.files(directory, pattern=".csv")
 monitorset <- as.vector(monitors[id])
      lapply(monitorset, function(x){
      t<- read.csv(x, header=TRUE)
      poll <- t[[pollutant]]
      mean(poll, na.rm)

 })     
}
```

When I call it:

```
pollutantmean(specdata, "sulfate")
```

I get this error message:

```
 Error in mean.default(poll, na.rm) : object 'na.rm' not found
```

I cannot figure out why the mean function thinks na.rm is an object when it should be an option.

I have tried running individual lines of the code in the console and as far as I can tell the other lines work as they should.  I have also googled the error and checked the mean() help entry but have not found a good explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't give the argument a value, just its name without the equal sign. You should use `mean(poll, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
mean(poll, na.rm)
```

To:

```
mean(poll, na.rm = TRUE)
```

or

```
mean(poll) # na.rm = FALSE
```

Alternatively, modify the function to support `na.rm` as a function parameter with the following:

```
# Adds the na.rm parameter to the function
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332, na.rm = TRUE) {
 monitors <- list.files(directory, pattern=".csv")
 monitorset <- as.vector(monitors[id])

 # Write an inline function w/ na.rm parameter.
 mread = function(x, na.rm = TRUE){
      t<- read.csv(x, header=TRUE)
      poll <- t[[pollutant]]
      mean(poll, na.rm = na.rm)
 }

 # Calculate and return result w/ function
 lapply(monitorset,FUN = mread, na.rm = na.rm)     
}
```